# primefaces 5.0 cannot set selected rows on datatable from backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

in my project I have two datatables flussiGuest and guestSummary that are linked: the ArrayList that feeds the selection of the former  feeds the value of the latter; I need to add elements to guestSummary from the backing bean;
 I read in other post that foer doing so  it is enough to add Items to the list that feeds the selection of the datatable, but in my case it does not work this is flussiGuest:

```
<p:dataTable var="rowItem" widgetVar="flussiGuest"
                    value="#{fileMatchMB.refactoredGuestList}"
                    selectionMode="multiple"
                    selection="#{fileMatchMB.refactoredSelectedGuests}"
                    rowKey="#{rowItem.pk_num}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100%"
                    id="tableFlussiGuest" rowClasses="list_odd_row,list_even_row"
                    styleClass="fluxTable" headerClass="fluxTableHeader">
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                        onsuccess="document.forms['frm_match'].submit()"
                        listener="#{fileMatchMB.onRowUnSelectGuest}" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                        onsuccess="document.forms['frm_match'].submit()"
                        listener="#{fileMatchMB.onRowSelectGuest}" />
                    <f:facet name="footer"> 
                        "#{fileMatchMB.countGuest} / #{fileMatchMB.refactoredGuestList.size()} #{msg.msg_records}"
                        </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="column1"
                        style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="column2"
                        style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="column3" styleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:80px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="column4" styleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column tyleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:10px;">
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

this is summaryGuest:

```
<p:dataTable var="rowItem" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100%"
                    id="GuestSummary"
                    emptyMessage="nessun flusso guest selezionato"
                    value="#{fileMatchMB.refactoredSelectedGuests}"
                    rowKey="#{rowItem.pk_num}">
                            style="width:10px;text-align:center" />
                        <p:column headerText="Date Valuta" width="30">
                        <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.val_date}">
                            <f:converter
                                converterId="filematch.interfaccia.CalendarConverter" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="column1"
                        style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="column2" styleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:80px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="column3" styleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
                    <p:column headerText="column4" styleClass="scrollableCell"
                        style="text-align: center; width:10px;">
                    </p:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer"> 
                        "#{fileMatchMB.refactoredSelectedGuests.size()} / #{fileMatchMB.refactoredGuestList.size()} #{msg.msg_records}"
                        </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
```

I think there is something that I am missing related with the life cycle of JSF because I can see that refactoredSelectedGuests   is correct for a moment, but before the view is rendered   it is reset to an empty ArrayList.

Comment: Why are you trying to hand-submit the JSF form (with `onsuccess="document.forms['frm_match'].submit()"`)?

Comment: because without it Icannot get  the other tables  updated,maybe there is another error some where, thanks

Comment: You should get a primer in ajax-rendering and updates using basic JSF and [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml)